# Expression Builder/Data Defined Labels Equally Spaced along Y Axis

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

[image]I want to create a series of labels that are organized vertically but equally spaced so they do not overlap.

I am using some data defined expressions to organize them along the X axis just fine. However, I would like to include a data defined expression that takes my highest and lowest $y coordinate (8 and 52 on the right hand side; 1 and 51 on the left hand side) and then organizes labels so that they do not overlap. This means that the y value for label 43 gets pushed closer to 52, etc.)

Does anybody have a good way of building an expression that accomplishes this?

Comment: Have the labels between y_min and y_max a special data driven order? For example number 2 must be under under number 8. You just want to move a label or do you although want to move the geometry? Can you explain the data defined expression for the x axis?

Comment: This is how I got the X axis: 

CASE WHEN $x > -100.922 THEN -100.898026
Else 
-100.942645
end

Because I rely on $x, they are already in order from bottom to top, so number 2 will be under number 8. 

I just want to move the label.

Comment: So the y-axis is order by the exisiting coordinates not by any field or attribute, id? Or could it be orderd by such a value?

Comment: The y axis would be ordered vertically by existing coordinates as I had imagined it, i.e. by highest Y value to lowest Y value, just spaced in a way that makes them not overlap.

It could also be ordered by a field, because I have lat/long coordinates as well.